# Crystal Report binding with Filtered Dataview

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am trying to sort the data in my crystal report at runtime. Theproblem is that i can only query the database once and that is at theloading of the report. At that time i fill up my dataset. Afterwards
when the sorted data is required, i use the Dataview's sort method and
sort the data. This sorted data is perfectly shown in the datagrid. Now
i want this data to be shown in my crystal report object too. Its not
working!!!
Can anyone tell me how can i make my dataview object bound to my crystal
report viewer object successfully?

Comment: show us some of your code!

Answer (score 0):

I'm new in c# and crystalReport..and my english is not good enough..but i will try to explain..i have 2 buttons in my form and the first one show my datagridview and i do some filter with `dataview.rowfilter =string s;` so when i hit the button the datagridview show me the filtered or sorted rows perfectly .and when i want to this data shown in Crystal report ,it's not working.. i define dataview globally and dv is global.and i used this code for binding to crystal report:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = this.dv.ToTable("Table");
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
rd.Load("CrystalReport1.rpt");
rd.SetDataSource(ds);
crystalReportViewer2.ReportSource = rd;
crystalReportViewer2.Show();
```

Comment: there is no one to answer my question ?